# tkinter ttk Radiobutton layout - apply padding between indicator and label

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Is it possible to add a padding between Radiobutton's label and the checkbox?
For example I want to move "Option 1" and "Option 2" texts to lower from their checkboxes:

[image]

```
screen = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(screen, width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

s = ttk.Style()

s.layout('TRadiobutton',
         [('Radiobutton.padding',
           {'children':
            [('Radiobutton.indicator', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'n'}),
             ('Radiobutton.focus', {'side': 'left',
                                    'children':
                                    [('Radiobutton.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                                    'sticky': ''})],
            'sticky': 'nswe'})])

r = StringVar()
r.set(" ")

def clicked(value):
    extension = value.get()

rb_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(screen, text="Audio", variable=r, value=".mp3", command= lambda: clicked(r.get()))
rb_2 = ttk.Radiobutton(screen, text="Video", variable=r, value=".mp4", command= lambda: clicked(r.get()))
canvas.create_window(255, 177, window=rb_1)
canvas.create_window(340, 177, window=rb_2)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: can labels be multi-line?

Comment: No, just one line please.

Comment: this may help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64899640/tkinter-radiobutton-how-to-align-multiline-text-with-the-button

Comment: @duruburak could you provide a [mre] ?

Comment: I added the styling layout of the Radiobutton, is that what you wanted from me?

Comment: @duruburak no, something to copy and paste that I could run. However, I think you can just place the components to stick to a side. AFAIK you can not use a specific number to adjust them. Shall I show you how you simulate something like this, but you would need to be careful that these radiobuttons don't get resized in your window.

Comment: @Thingamabobs I updated the code as you requested, let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically the trick to simulate what you want is to use `ipady` which is available for `grid` and `pack`. Example:

```
rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='abc')
rad_button.pack(expand=False, fill=None,ipady=15)
```

Then all you need to do is to stick the parts to the right side with a layout that could look like this:

```
style.layout(style_name,
             [('Radiobutton.padding',
               {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                   ('Radiobutton.indicator',{'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''}),
                   ('Radiobutton.focus',{'side': 'bottom', 'sticky': '',
                                         'children':
                   [('Radiobutton.label', {
                       'side': 'left','sticky': ''})]})]})])
```

Result on Windows 11 with theme `default` looks like:

[image]

**Be aware that this does not add padding between the two elements**, it just sets extra space inside the widget with `ipady` and sticks them to `top` and `bottom` of that space.

---

**Update:**

For canvas you can specify the option `height` to achieve a similar result with `create_window`

Comment: This worked out but if there's a version of this with canvas function that would be super helpful because I use canvas to create windows, I don't use pack().

Comment: @duruburak `canvas.create_window(255, 177, window=rb_1, height=100)`